# leaflet jupyter plot color density heat map

Tags: python, leaflet, jupyter

I'm working on a pandas csv dataframe and came to know in jupyter using `ipyleaflet` you can plot to a map.

My code so far looks like this

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, Marker, MarkerCluster

longitudes = df['Longitude'].values.tolist()
latitudes = df['Latitude'].values.tolist()

markers = []

for lon,lat in zip(longitudes, latitudes):
    markers.append(Marker(location=(lat, lon)))

m = Map(center=(latitudes[0], longitudes[0]), zoom=10)

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster(
    markers=markers
)

m.add_layer(marker_cluster);

m
```

[image]

Which is nice but then I saw this

[image]

I also have the same field `Economic Need Index` so I also want to do the same and also curious how I can also switch to the `CartoDB` less busy map.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [last version of ipyleaflet](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/releases/tag/0.9.0) it is now possible to create a HeatMap:

```python
from ipyleaflet import Map, Heatmap
from random import uniform

m = Map(center=[0, 0], zoom=2)

# Create a random heatmap
locations = [
    [uniform(-80, 80), uniform(-180, 180), uniform(0, 1000)] # lat, lng, intensity 
    for i in range(1000)
]
heat = Heatmap(locations=locations, radius=20, blur=10)
m.add_layer(heat)

# Change some attributes of the heatmap
heat.radius = 30
heat.blur = 50
heat.max = 0.5
heat.gradient = {0.4: 'red', 0.6: 'yellow', 0.7: 'lime', 0.8: 'cyan', 1.0: 'blue'}

m
```

Also, if you want to switch to a "less busy map", you can change the basemap when creating it:

```python
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps

m = Map(center=(52, 10), zoom=8, basemap=basemaps.CartoDB.DarkMatter)
m
```

And you can also create a TileLayer given the url of the tiles, you can find examples in the [documentation](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: heatmap generated is different from a density pointer per location

Comment: With the current state of ipyleaflet you can only have something similar to the screenshot you gave. Your first option would be to use the Heatmap widget. The second one would be to display a list of Circle widgets on the map, with the color/opacity of the circles which depends on the density.